# Delete duplicates files with powershell based on their name and file contents

Tags: powershell

I am really new to powershell, really need help with this.
I have a directory with multiple folders with multiple files, some files in different folders are having the same name with or without the same content. All I need to do is to filter out all the files with the same name and with the same content and move them to the other folder.

I tried the way using in this link
https://sid-500.com/2020/04/26/find-duplicate-files-with-powershell/
the issue here is that get-filehash can find the duplicates by contents, but not by name (for example: dir\a\a.txt and dir\a\b.txt will be considered as duplicates but I want dir\a\a.txt and dir\b\a.txt be the duplicates) and also it cannot identify empty files.

Comment: Knowing that `get-filehash` is pretty expensive, you better first [compare the files](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=powershell+compare+files) and than for what's equal, check the hashes.

Comment: `Group-Object` takes multiple key properties - you don't have to group on the hash alone: `Group-Object Hash,{$_.Path |Split-Path -Leaf}`